# Cómo puedo hacer este tipo de Card con Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap, css-grid-layout

Viendo la documentación de bottstrap, en específico la documentación del componente "cards" vi un una card de publicidad de slack. Dónde hay un recuadro con fondo gris, dentro de él una imagen del lado izquierdo y texto de lado derecho. Quiero hacer una así, pero paradójicamente no hay documentación de como hacer una así, solo se puede poner una imagen y el texto de bajo, no a un lado.

Me gustaría poner dos de esos en una fila.

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-sm-20">
       <div class="exprience-thumb" style="background: url(img/e1.jpg);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="exprience-content">
        <h2>From the root of experience <br> We dig out the best talent</h2>
        <h6 class="sub-exprience-title">Few would argue that, despite the advancements of feminism over the past three decades, women still face a double standard when it comes to their behavior. While men’s borderline.</h6>
        <p>inappropriate behavior is often laughed off as “boys will be boys,” women face higher conduct standards – especially in the workplace. That’s why it’s crucial that, as women, our behavior on the job is beyond reproach.Small Towns and Big StatesFor evidence of the double standard.</p>
        <a href="#" class="primary-btn">View Details</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-sm-20">
       <div class="exprience-thumb" style="background: url(img/e1.jpg);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="exprience-content">
        <h2>From the root of experience <br> We dig out the best talent</h2>
        <h6 class="sub-exprience-title">Few would argue that, despite the advancements of feminism over the past three decades, women still face a double standard when it comes to their behavior. While men’s borderline.</h6>
        <p>inappropriate behavior is often laughed off as “boys will be boys,” women face higher conduct standards – especially in the workplace. That’s why it’s crucial that, as women, our behavior on the job is beyond reproach.Small Towns and Big StatesFor evidence of the double standard.</p>
        <a href="#" class="primary-btn">View Details</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: favor de leer [ask], la idea no es solo poner lo que deseas hacer sino lo que has intentado y lo que ya no te quedó para apartir de ahi ayudarte

Comment: Saludos bro, de pura casualidad ¿conoces CSS?

Comment: Perdón, ahora agrego el código. Lo que intenté fue ignorar las cards, y hacer todo con divs, pero al momento de agregar lo que serían dos "cards" se mueve el texto hacía abajo.

Comment: fredyfx. Si ya se que es algo muy básico solo que no suelo usar bottstrap, y este proyecto está todo en bootstrap, y quería saber si ya tiene algo implementado, como por ejemplo Materializecss ya las implementa, las llama cards horizontales

Comment: No me refiero a que si es básico o no, sucede que muchos programadores nuevos quieren ir de frente a manejar frameworks sin pasar por un entrenamiento en lo básico, luego su nivel de estrés y frustración se eleva, para evitar todo esto, pregunto en si conocen lo básico y qué tanto conocen, de esta manera puedo dar enlaces de recursos más acorde con lo que se busca desarrollar o en el mejor de los casos, dar una buena respuesta, ¿me dejo entender?

Comment: Si sé css, de hecho es la manera en la que me gusta trabajar más, con bootstrap siento que trabajo el doble por que acabo editando todas las clases que tiene para los resultados que quiero.

Comment: @JoséCarlosCastillo brother, al trabajar con bootstrap o cualquier framework de CSS, se toma como base las clases que existen y se agrega tus propias clases extendiendo el código del framework, por algo se llama CSS, si tienes problemas con clases que se escriben y se sobre escriben generando comportamientos inesperados, recuerda poner al último la clase que quiere que "domine". Editar las clases del framework es una mala idea, luego llega otro programador, mira la documentación, usa las clases y perderá más tiempo tratando de entender los cambios que hay, te lo digo en buen plan :D

Comment: Es justo lo que me esta pasando, modificaron bootstrap, le movieron a los mediaquerys y a no sé que tanto más y estoy sufriendo mucho. Mañana le preguntaré al otro programados que más le movió.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89044/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-jose-carlos-castillo).

Answer (score 2):

La mejor manera de hacerlo no es con las `cards` de Boostrap. Yo lo haría con el componente [`media-object`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/media-object/)

Te permite posicionar de forma fácil una imagen dentro de un `wrap`. Lee la documentación, es muy completa.

Aparte estoy usando las [utilidades de espacio](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/) para añadir un padding al contenedor `media`

```css
.media {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  width: 400px;  
}

.media img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="media p-4">
  <img src="https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/41629/1547651715-slack-carbon-white_2x.png" class="align-self-center mr-3">
  <div class="media-body">
    <p>The easiest way to sign docs, forms and agreements online. Try it free today.</p>
    <span>Ads via Carbon</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```